# having clause works with where in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, where-clause, having

Here is the schema
Employee (name,sex,salary,deptName)
and name is the primary key

```
SELECT deptname
FROM employee
WHERE sex=m
GROUP BY deptName HAVING avg(salary) >
  (SELECT avg(salary)
   FROM employee)
```

I want to understand the part `having avg(salary)` what does that part actually do?
since we dont include the salary select clause,

```
SELECT deptname
FROM employee
WHERE sex=m
GROUP BY deptName
```

This part will give me group of deptName, just one column nothing else, I am wondering how having (avg(salary)) is working, it is taking avg of all employees from the table or what?

Anyone who can tell me
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE` filters records *before* they are grouped; whereas `HAVING` filters the results *after* they have been grouped.  Expressions, using functions or operators, can be used in either clause (although aggregate functions like `AVG()` cannot be used in the `WHERE` clause as the records would not have been grouped when that clause is evaluated).

Thus your query filters a list of departments for those where the average salary of that department's male workers is greater than the overall (company) average salary.

Comment: that wasn't my question, I know we cant use aggregate functions in where clause, I just wanted to know what having avg(salary) is donig in this case

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT AVG(salary)
   FROM employee
```

By above query first you will get avg salary of all employees.

Now you are getting only department whose avg salary is greater than avg salary of all employees.

Comment: getting that, it returns avg salary of dept but with only male employees

Comment: dont we need to use avg(salary) in select statement as well?

Comment: I think you are saying avg(salary) instead of having avg(salary)...if this is then I want to clear you that here your query is not fetching avg salary but here avg(salary) is a condition to filter data...hope you will be getting answer of your query.

Comment: Yes if you want department wise avg salary along with their name then you should use in select also.

Answer (score 0):

The having clause works like a where condition for the '**group by deptName**' clause. All rows are grouped by value of deptName column. For each group, the average is calculated on the values of salary for that particular group.

Therefore, for all groups, only if the average salary for that particular 'deptName' group is greater than the average salary for all employees, the row from that group would show.

Answer (score 0):

having is like WHERE clause but its for aggregate functions Like AVG.

so your query will look for average of every deptname. BUT in your query

```
 having avg(salary) > (select  avg(salary) from employee)
```

you maybe want give an average to compare with.

like

```
   having avg(salary) > 25
```

so this will select only those who have average > 25.

Comment: its doing nothing? I read that it is getting the avg salaries of Male employees , which make me confused

Comment: yes its doing , it select the average , then you want select only average which is greater then the actual avg.

Comment: I think it is wrong that this query doing nothing as this will provide all department name whose avg salary (department wise) greater than avg salary of all employees.